# How to automatically insert page numbers to hyperlink destination text anchors in Adobe InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, ebook

I'm using Adobe InDesign to make a PDF that will have links to pages within itself (e.g. a text on page 10 links to the text on page 32).

I'm using "New Hyperlink Destination" to create Text Anchors (so, for example, a text anchor "Footnote" on page 32). Then I link to this Text Anchor from the text on page 10 using Interactive -> New Hyperlink -> Text Anchor.

This all works fine, However, how I do make InDesign automatically insert page numbers for the appropriate Text Anchors? For instance, if Text Anchor "Footnote" changes its location from page 32 to page 40, how would I make InDesign reflect this change automatically and put in the appropriate page number? Is that at all possible actually?

Comment: See [cross references](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/cross-references.html) in InDesign's online help.

Comment: @RadLexus thank you, it worked! if you want you could post it as an answer, so I can accept it, because it's not so obvious where to look for in the manual and what to look for :)

Comment: Thanks, but I have only very limited experience with using them. But you could outline in an answer how *you* solved it - you can also 'accept' a self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

Awesome!
Here is the answer:

1. Find Cross-References tab, open it.
2. Select your text that you want to it changeable.
3. Click [+] in Cross-References tab.
4. Choose Destination, from your previous paragraph/character styles.
5. Edit how to make that selected text to be from Cross-References Format, in the same window. You can edit a new format from clicking the pencil ✏️ icon, you can make new codes.